# Filter / Slicer Modification (PowerBI)

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, bar-chart, slicers

I have sets of data from January to December, to be illustrated in a monthly bar chart. Is it possible to set a slicer that will show figures from January to selected month?

For example, if you click "August", the bar chart will show a bar from January to August instead of August alone.

Is it possible to set a slicer that will show figures from January to selected month?

Comment: A between slicer normally does the job there, is this not an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You will need a separate table for the month slicer.
Add a new table similar to:

| Month | MonthNum |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 |
| Feb | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| Nov | 11 |
| Dec | 12 |

Then you can use a measure similar to:

```
MyTotal = 
  var maxD = MAX('Month'[MonthNum]) // 'Month' is the name of the new table
  RETURN IF( MONTH(MAX('DimDate'[Date])) <= maxD, [Total] )
```

Then for your chart, use the Month from your date table as the X-Axis (and not the one from the new table above).

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does the [Total] refers to?

Comment: Apologies - `Total = SUM('Sale'[Amount])`

Comment: I assume the slicer will only work for one specific visual, correct? What if my dashboard/report contains multiple visuals (bar chart, line chart, pie chart, etc) and i want the slicer to interact with all of the visuals? is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried it? That slicer will work with all visuals so long as they use the `MyTotal` measure.

Comment: yup, works fine now. i misinterpreted your comment earlier on. thank you for the help! I'll comment on this post again if i encounter some problem ^^

Comment: Super, please accept the answer for the benefit of all